# Biholomorphism between lower-half-disk and upper-half-plane, with two conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I would like to find a holomorphic map that transforms the lower half unit-disk into the upper half-plane, with two constraints:

- the image of the boundary [-1,1] of the half-disk is $\infty$
- the image of the boundary point -i is 0.

Thank you if someone has ideas.

Edit: (some precisions on background)

My question comes from analysis of elliptic PDEs.

I know an explicit formula for a harmonic function $u$ in the upper half-plane $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+^\star$, that satisfies a certain Neumann boundary condition on the boundary $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 0 \}$. The boundary condition is precisely $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} = -\frac{1}{2}\sin(2(u-g))$ where $g$ is given by $\nu=ie^{ig}$, $\nu$ being the outer unit normal on the boundary of the domain.

Now, I would like to find an explicit formula for a harmonic function in the lower half-disk, that satisfies the same Neumann boundary condition as before, on a boundary that remains to find (but it is not the question here).

My strategy is to transform the upper half-plane into the lower half-disk using a biholomorphism $\phi$, because I will then be sure that the composition $u \circ \phi^{-1}$ is harmonic in the lower half-disk (as a composition of a harmonic function and a holomorphic function).

If I represent the vectors $(\cos u,\sin u)$ in the upper half-plane, the point $0$ is "repulsive". As I want additionally to keep the "behaviour" of these vectors for the composition $u \circ \phi^{-1}$, I ask two conditions for $\phi^{-1}$: $\phi^{-1}(-i)=0$ and $\phi^{-1}(x)=\infty$ for $x\in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Hint: start with the following mobius map f(z)=(z-1)/(z+1).. later on you'll might want use g(z)=z^2

Comment: Thank you @zokomoko. If I follow your hint, I think you want to say that your map f transforms the lower half-disk into the quadrant $\{ x,y<0 \}$, then I can multiply by $i^2$ to obtain the first quadrant, and then take the square to obtain the upper half-plane. So the map would be $z \mapsto ((z-1)/(z+1))^2$, but my constraints are not satisfied... The image of $[-1,1]$ is the positive real axis and the image of $-i$ is $-1$, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Any conformal map between Jordan domains (on the sphere) extends to a homeomorphism of the closures, so it is not possible that your map takes a whole interval to just the one point $\infty$.